# jq how to choose from unique keys based on values

Tags: json, command-line, jq, data-manipulation

I've been learning more about JSON lately and stumbled upon the "jq" command-line JSON processor. I am trying to combine multiple json files regarding clones from our Github repository. Some of these dates overlap, and since they were accessed at different points of the day, have slightly different count and unique values. Here is an example:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-24T00:00:00Z",
    "count": 1,
    "uniques": 1
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-24T00:00:00Z",
    "count": 2,
    "uniques": 1
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-24T00:00:00Z",
    "count": 3,
    "uniques": 2
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-25T00:00:00Z",
    "count": 12,
    "uniques": 5
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-25T00:00:00Z",
    "count": 15,
    "uniques": 9
  }
]
```

The resulting code should look at the timestamp, determine whether it is unique, and if not, keep the object containing the largest "count". An example of the desired output is below:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-24T00:00:00Z",
    "count": 3,
    "uniques": 2
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-25T00:00:00Z",
    "count": 15,
    "uniques": 9
  }
]
```

"jq" seems to be a pretty useful tool and I've managed to use it in a few other situations, but haven't been able to figure out if or how to utilize it in this sort of fashion. Any help (or direction) would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple but efficient solution can be obtained by using these two generic helper functions:

```
def aggregate_by(s; f; g):
  reduce s as $x  (null; .[$x|f] += [$x|g]);

def max_by(s; f):
  reduce s as $s (null;
    if . == null then {s: $s, m: ($s|f)}
    else  ($s|f) as $m
    | if $m > .m then {s: $s, m: $m} else . end
    end)
  | .s ;
```

With these, a solution is the two-liner:

```
[ aggregate_by(.[]; .timestamp; .)[]
  | max_by(.[]; .count) ]
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly, thanks for the help! Any advice for tutorials or the likes for "jq"? Been reading through the man page, but haven't seen a ton of tutorials on the tool

Comment: The following sequence works for many: (1) working through the official jq tutorial at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/; (2) skimming the manual; (3) one or more of: browsing the FAQ, the Cookbook, my own "Stream-Oriented Introduction to jq" (https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq), and/or the "jq Language Description" at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/jq-Language-Description